# Proving that definitions of closures are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been working through Herbert Endertons Elements of set theory and I have stumbled upon an exercise which I can not solve.Here is how it goes:

Let  $A \subseteq B$ and let $f:B\to B$.

Now let $C^*=\bigcap \{X|A\subseteq X \subseteq B $ and $f[X] \subseteq$$ X \}$,namely it is intersection of supersets of A which are closed under f.

Now let function $h:\omega \to B$ such that: $$h(0) = A$$ $$h(n^+)=h(n)\cup f[h(n)]$$

Finally let $C_* = \bigcup ran\;h = \bigcup_{ i \in \omega}h(i)$

I need to prove that $C^*=C_*$ by proving that they are subsets of each other thus equivalent.

On first part there is a hint which confuses me.Namely it states that to prove $C^* \subseteq C_*$ it is sufficient to prove that $f[C_*] \subseteq C_*$

Could someone tell me why is it sufficient to prove the second claim,and how using that claim can we conclude that $C^* \subseteq C_*$

Reference: Herbert Enderton , Elements of set theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the claim $ C^\ast \subseteq C_\ast $, we have to look at the definition of $ C^\ast $. This is the intersection of sets of the type $ X $ with $ A \subseteq X \subseteq B $ and $ f [X] \subseteq X $. So if we can show that $ C_\ast $ satisfies those two conditions, it is part of the system we take the intersection of.

So the hint is perhaps a little bit misleading,  since to show that $ C_\ast $ satisfies $ f [C_\ast] \subseteq C_\ast $ is only half the proof. The other half is to show, that $ A \subseteq C_\ast \subseteq B $ holds. I think the author omits that, because it is rather clear from the definition.

Comment: Omg if I could give you milion points I would,but I cant.I am endlessly thankful my sir...